# Pass parameters for ocx registration during installation in VS setup project

Tags: installation, setup-project, registration, ocx, license-key

I have an **OCX** that requires licensing in order for it to work. The vendor tells me to register it this way:

**regsvr32.exe "widget.ocx" "/i:licensekey" /s**

I am using **Visual Studio 2008 Setup Project** where the OCX is detected as a dependency. I have the Register property set to "vsdrfCOMSelfReg". However, I don't see a way of passing the /s and /i parameters. This causes the OCX registration process to display a registration dialog to the user, which I don't want.

Any idea how I can pass the license key during OCX installation in VS Setup Project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the file is registered in a special way, "vsdrfCOMSelfReg" won't work. Instead, you can try using a custom action which runs the registration command.

Basically, you can write custom code which launches regsvr32.exe with the appropriate command line. For example, you can use [ShellExecute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762153%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: I was trying to avoid doing this, but it does appear to be the only way. Ended up calling into the install class where I wrote code in the Commit function to launch the registration command.